# Once Apache Beam supports Python 3, will tf.data be integrated into tf.Transform?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-transform

Reading about TFX, Kubeflow, Beam, Flink and [a neverending stream of Apache projects](https://pixelastic.github.io/pokemonorbigdata/) I'm getting more and more confused. I'm curious what the TensorFlow team intends to promote to the canonical ETL API for training Keras models.

I'm currently pretty happy with `tf.data` support in `tf.keras` but two things are sorely missing:

1. Dataset reductions for standardizing features/targets.
2. Full dataset shuffling with persistent per-element caching (e.g. an equivalent of doing index permutations with a NumPy memmap).

My hunch is `tf.data` exists because `tf.Transform` [only works on Python 2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251). Once that is finally fixed, what's the future for `tf.data`? Will it be integrated into `tf.Transform` or the other way around? Will `tf.data` get the above mentioned features eventually, independently of Apache Beam's status?

**TL;DR: What's going to be the canonical ETL API for training Keras models? Could a TensorFlower clarify the plans for the TensorFlow ecosystem and how it all ought to fit together?**

*PS: Where does `tensorflow_io` and `tensorflow_datasets` fit into all of this? They seem to do a lot of reinventing of the wheel instead of relying on `tf.Transform`.*

Comment: I don't see anywhere say that TF Transform works in Python 2 only. The badge in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform) and the [PyPI project page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-transform/) both suggest Python 2.7+ and Python 3.5+ should work. Same for [apache-beam](https://pypi.org/project/apache-beam/). I don't think that's the reason why it is a separate package, I think the reason is that most TF users do not need or want to have Apache Beam installed. `tf.data` has become quite central to TF, so I don't think it is going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: About `tensorflow_io`, it is really just about supporting data sources. It is also useful for people who do not use Beam or similar, and I suppose it adds too much "vendor-specific" stuff to be mainstream TF. `tensorflow_datasets` is just a set of datasets with a particular API. Again, I think it's too specific for main TF, even just the generic parts of it, and it is more or less disconnected from the rest of TF up until `as_dataset`. That said, there seems to be some redoubled efforts that could eventually be refactored.